# C# static objects with shared interface - is this viable?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I'm almost certain what I'm trying to do isn't possible, but I'm hoping I've missed a trick in the book.

I'm working on a project where an object can have a variety of attributes. Each attribute can have a distinct set of values. Right now, those attributes and values are referred to using an internal `Dictionary<string, string>` (which I can't do anything about) and hardcoded magic lookup strings.

```
if (dog.attribute("color") == "black" || dog.attribute("color") == "brown") {
    //...
}
```

Naturally, this is causing problems as the number of attributes and values grows and becomes more complex. I want to turn this into something object-based, so I can group attribute names and valid values. Enum sounds perfect for this, but the string typing on all attribute names and values breaks that idea. I thought about string constants instead:

```
public class Color {
    public const string AttributeName = "color";
    public const string DefaultValue = Black;

    public const string Black = "black";
    public const string Brown = "brown";
}

//...
if (dog.attribute(Color.AttributeName) == Color.Black || dog.attribute(Color.AttributeName) == Color.Brown) {
    //...
}
```

This is better for maintenance, but still pretty ugly, and I have no way of enforcing the presence of `AttributeName` and `DefaultValue` constants. I thought about inherited properties:

```
public abstract class DogAttribute {
    public abstract string AttributeName { get; }
    public abstract string DefaultValue { get; }
}

public class DogColor : DogAttribute {
    public override string AttributeName => "color";
    public override string DefaultValue => Black;

    public string Black => "black";
    public string Brown => "brown";
}
```

But now I sacrifice the ability to refer to the attribute statically.

```
//really really bad
if (dog.attribute(new DogColor().AttributeName) == new DogColor().Black || dog.attribute(new DogColor().AttributeName) == new DogColor().Brown) {
    //...
}

//better, but still really bad given how heavily attributes are used
DogColor dogColor = new DogColor();
if (dog.attribute(dogColor.AttributeName) == dogColor.Black || dog.attribute(dogColor.AttributeName) == dogColor.Brown) {
    //...
}
```

I am 99% certain that the combination of wanting to refer to these attribute objects statically and wanting these attribute objects to have some sort of standard interface is impossible together. Am I missing a valid implementation option, or some not-completely-awful way of refactoring this string soup? (I doubt it matters, but using reflection is not viable. Refactoring has to keep performance intact.)

Comment: At their core Enums are nothing but named constants, with automatic values, grouping and type checking. One thing you could do is add a "translation layer" between the Enum input/output and the string storage. A simple array of string constants would do it and you could use enums as index That would give you time to migrate of the string constants and towards Enumerations. One thing worth a look for you might be the ExpandoObject. At it's core it is a Dictionary<String, object> with property like change notification and some Syntax sugar, so it might make a good replacement for this construct.

Comment: There are too many solutions, your question is too broad. You need to _try_ something, and then if you have trouble, seek help with whatever _specific_ issue you are having. That said, there's nothing wrong with using `Enum.Parse()` to convert string values that come from outside your code to the enum values needed for the internal workings of your code. I think an enum-based solution would work fine.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have tried several things, all elaborated upon in the question, and not been especially happy with any of them. Implementation isn't the issue here. Design is. `Enum.Parse` will get me an attribute *name*, but not its *value*. Or, given an attribute Enum, Enum.Parse can get me its value, I suppose. In case I didn't explain well enough - each attribute can be considered its own enum, with its own collection of valid values, but *everything* is a string internally. Enum.Parse will require a minimum two parses per attribute query.

Answer (score 0):

I think singleton is good choice here:

```
 public class DogColor : DogAttribute {
        public static DogAttribute Instance;

        public override string AttributeName => "color";
        public override string DefaultValue => Black;

        public string Black => "black";
        public string Brown => "brown";
 }
```